# AWS Amplify Cache Utility usage

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I am trying to save and retrieve data in a React Native app using the Cache Utility provide by AWS Amplify. I used the following code:

```
Cache.setItem("FirstName","Donald");
const firstName = Cache.getItem("FirstName");
console.log(firstName);
```

I am expecting that console.log will print "Donald", however console output prints:

```
Promise {
7:50:31 PM:   "_40": 0,
7:50:31 PM:   "_55": null,
7:50:31 PM:   "_65": 0,
7:50:31 PM:   "_72": null,
7:50:31 PM: }
```

AWS Reference document: https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/cache_guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning a promise. therefore you can either use `async-await` or chain a `.then` to get the result.

```
// works only inside async functions
await Cache.setItem("FirstName","Donald");
const firstName = await Cache.getItem("FirstName");
```

**OR**

```
Cache.getItem("FirstName").then(result => {
    if(result) {
      console.log(result)
    }
})
```